# Rails i18n gem excludes attribute name from error messages for non-English locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n

The Rails app I am working on uses the Japanese locale.
In order to use default translations for error messages, I installed the [`rails-i18n`](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n) gem, but I am having trouble getting it to display full error messages.

```rb
# Locale configuration in application.rb
config.i18n.default_locale = :ja
```

Before installing this gem, the error messages for validation errors told me that the translation is missing, as expected.

```
*** ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid Exception: translation missing: ja.activerecord.errors.messages.record_invalid
```

However, even after installing the gem, the Japanese translation for the same message does not include the attribute whose validation failed. The blank space after the final colon is supposed to be the attribute name.

```
*** ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid Exception: バリデーションに失敗しました: を入力してください
```

To illustrate, this is what the error message looks like with the locale set to `:en`. In Japanese, it's as if the column name `First name` is missing, so the error message reads `<No subject> can't be blank`.

```
*** ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid Exception: Validation failed: First name can't be blank
```

What am I missing here? Do I need some additional configuration?
Thank you for any help in advance.

---

Note: I use rails 6.0.0.

Comment: The gem only provides translations for the default error messages. All other texts including the name of certain attributes are not translated by that gem. You need to provide translations for all models and attributes yourself. Did you do that?

Comment: No, I was under the impression that the gem would insert the attribute names in English. That was the behaviour in a different Rails project using the same i18n gem - the same error message would look like this: `バリデーションに失敗しました: First nameを入力してください`.

Comment: Then you probably defined the translations to fallback to English and not to raise errors in that project. I advise reading about [internationalization in the Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

Comment: Dif you check config/locales/ja.yml? You also need to restart the server.

Comment: Regarding: _"Then you probably defined the translations to fallback to English and not to raise errors in that project."_
I don't recall doing anything like that, and `config.i18n.fallbacks = true` is setup for both projects. But I will see if there's anything else that may be causing this difference.

Comment: @demir You're right! It was because someone else working on the project had defined errors' formats to be this: `%{message}`. So the `attribute` part of the error had been omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @demir suspected, it was because of configuration done to amend the format of error messages. This caused the `attribute` part to be omitted from error messages.

```
# Original format
format: "%{attribute} %{message}"

# Configured format
format: "%{message}"
```